# MySQL doesn't show Execution Plan when using Explain

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to use 'Explain Current Statement' on MySQL Workbench, but without sucess.

The query that I'm running is:

```
explain select c.customerName, o.orderNumber, o.shippedDate, o.comments from orders as o 
inner join customers as c on o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
where c.customerNumber = 128
```

The query itself runs and returns me results, but when I go to 'Explain Current Statement' or 'Execution Plain' it gives me theses errors:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'explain select c.customerName, o.orderNumber,
> o.shippedDate, o.comments from ord' at line 1

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you run the select without explain ? and what versions of mysql and mysqlworkbench are you on?

Comment: you already have an `explain` query. You can't explain that further.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, I can run without the explain.

Comment: Holy sh*t @Barmar, I removed the explain from the query and not it works! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When using MySQL Workbench, you have to remove the 'explain' word from the SQL command in orther to use the 'Explain Current Statement' tool.